# Inline xsd import in spring boot ws results in message types and operations from all wsdl

Tags: spring-boot, xsd, wsdl, spring-ws

I followed this stack overflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42112775/spring-ws-wsdl-automatic-exposure-xsd-import-are-not-followed/50085950) to add multiple inline schemas as import to parent schema and able to generate and load the wsdl in soap UI but the generated wsdl have the message types and operations from other schemas as well which is not expected as it exposes unwanted operations to client.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to rules for generating dynamic wsdl. The generated WSDL will follow these rules, you may have elements ending with Request and Response causing this problem.

> The  builds a WSDL from a XSD schema by using
>   conventions. It iterates over all element elements found in the
>   schema, and creates a message for all elements. Next, it creates WSDL
>   operation for all messages that end with the defined request or
>   response suffix. The default request suffix is Request; the default
>   response suffix is Response, though these can be changed by setting
>   the requestSuffix and responseSuffix attributes on ,
>   respectively. It also builds a portType, binding, and service based on
>   the operations.

**Ref:**https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html